# Passing data from service to fragment

Tags: android, service, android-fragments

I want to pass a data from a service to a fragment . Here my code in the service

```
public void putInfo(){
    Intent trIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    trIntent.setClass(this,WelcomeActivity.class);
    trIntent.putExtra("info", strengthAmplitude+"");
    trIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(trIntent);
    }
```

And then I want to  use this data ("info") in my fragment (InfoFragment) like that

```
  String msg =  getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("info");
```

I am getting errors.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(25036): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service 
com.BackupAndTools.service.InfoService@41e6b498 with Intent { 
cmp=com.BackupAndTools/.service.InfoService }: 
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class 
{com.BackupAndTools/com.BackupAndTools.views.InfoFragment}; have you declared this 
activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

while it is a fragment not an activity to be declared in AndroidManifets.xml !!

Comment: I think you have to implement one Activity and through that activity call the Fragment, your problem will solve marya

Comment: In fact that is what I do actually. I call the fragment (InfoFragment) from an Activity (WelcomeActivity).I edited my  code as you suggested so take a look pleaze. But I still can't get the data because I have a NullPointerException in this line   
String msg =  getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("info"); in the fragment

Comment: Ya, then call that Activity from Service also.

Comment: try putting String msg =  ((WelcomeActivity)getActivity()).getIntent().getExtras().getString("info");

But you should also send an intent to the parent activity, not the fragment itself.

Comment: @Marya There should be other way also marya, if its feasible to your code

Comment: @androbat I edited my code and the problem remianes !!

Comment: @pratik what do you sugggest ??

Comment: @Marya http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52590/discussion-for-passing-data-from-service-to-fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding a receiver in your Fragment :

```
class CustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String data= intent.getExtra(DATA);
    }
}
```

Now in your Fragment register the receiver with a intent filter:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    receiver = new CustomReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(MY_TRIGGER);
    getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}
```

Now in your Service:

```
public class NumberThoery extends Service {


public static String MY_TRIGGER = "trigger";

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    intent.putExtra(DATA,"test");
    sendBroadcast(intent,MY_TRIGGER);
    return START_STICKY;
}



@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```